# Skipping a chunk of data when using fpassthru

Tags: php, http-headers, fsockopen

I'm trying to set up a simple PHP script to emulate an audio file with fpassthru.

However, the source that I'm pulling the content from naturally adds headers to the actual data-stream fetched by my PHP script, which I think is the reason my setup doesn't work.

What I'd like to do is skip/ignore the first 13 lines/289 bytes of the data fetched by fpassthru, so the stream is "clean" and uncontaminated with headers from the original server - is this possible?

here's my current code:

```
// Make socket connection
$errno = "errno";
$errstr = "errstr";
$fp = fsockopen($ip, $port, $errno, $errstr, 30);

if(!$fp) exit;

// Create send headers
fputs($fp, "GET /$path HTTP/1.0\r\n");
fputs($fp, "Host: $ip\r\n");
fputs($fp, "User-Agent: Script\r\n");
fputs($fp, "Accept: */*\r\n");
fputs($fp, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");

// Write the returned data back to the resource
fpassthru($fp);

// close the socket when we're done
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: can you post your current code? just to get the better picture of what are you trying to do here

Comment: Try fread-ing until you hit the end of the headers and use fpassthru afterwards. You'll notice the end of the headers when you've read a double new line (\n).

Comment: Can you explain how to make fread stop at that point?